# Why did Queen Amidala have to raise the vote of no confidence?

Tags: star-wars

Why did [Palpatine](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Palpatine) have to convince [Queen Amidala](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Padm%C3%A9_Amidala) to raise the vote of no confidence against [Chancellor Valorum](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Finis_Valorum)?  If everyone in the Senate hated the Chancellor why didn't someone else do it or Palpatine just raise the motion himself?

Same goes for the motion to grant emergency powers.  I feel like he had to trick Jar-Jar into doing it.

Comment: this is explained in detail in the Darth Plageus book.  It gives a lot of background as to why.  Sorry I don't have it handy to quote, but check it out if you want the answers.

Answer (score 14):

It is a subtle machination:

1. The trade Federation blockades Naboo forcing Queen Amidala to ask help in the Senate.
2. Because of bureaucratic inertia nothing is done (as expected), prompting her to raise the no-confidence vote.
3. Because of the increasing tension the vote succeeds.
4. Because of sympathy for the poor Naboo, Representative Palpatine gathers a majority of votes to succeed Valorum.

So the whole maneuver is planned to bring Palpatine (who was not particularly high ranked) to prominence. Notice that Palpatine suggests the vote and acts surprised when elected, but that Darth Sidious had very concrete orders for which planet to blockade.

Why Amidala and not Palpatine himself? So that the whole thing looks like an authentic cry of desperation by the Queen instead of like an obvious power grab (it does not look good to call the no-confidence vote yourself and then get in the succession ballot).

Answer (score 4):

Not everyone in the senate hated Chancellor Valorum. That was the whole point: Palpatine needed to oust a well-liked chancellor, without actually appearing to have anything to do with it. Hence getting Amidala to make an emotional appeal, and making sure his other dupes, the Trade Federation delegates, acted as obnoxious as possible, but in a way that still satisfied the letter of the law, so that Valorum's hands were tied.

And whatever gives you the idea that Palpatine ***didn't*** trick Jar-Jar into making the motion to grant emergency powers? Again, *that was the point*.

Comment: What I mean is why did he have to trick jar jar into doing that.  He could have just done it himself.  So if the Queen never voted out Valoroum this whole mess wouldn't have happened?  I feel like Palpetine didn't do anything to help the Queen as they captured the Viceroy themselves.  If anything Valoroum was more of a help than Palpetine was.

Comment: Also I was under the impression Valoroum was NOT well liked hence all the delegates chanting "Vote now!" and the fact that he actually got voted out.

Comment: @ooooo444434: "done it himself"? Are you serious? "Oh, hi, I want unlimited power, why don't y'all just give it to me." Yeah, that'd work. Not.

Answer (score -1):

If your asking why Amidala specifically had to ask the question the answer is she didn't but she was the easiest pawn for Palpatine to use in that situation.

If your asking why the question had to be asked and why Palpatine wouldn't do it himself the answer is that the Sith like to be  [The Chessmaster](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheChessmaster)

if your asking why Palpatine wanted to get rid of Valloroum well thats kinda obvious